# Julia: Parallel code slower than sequential code

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, julia

I am trying to use parallelization to speed up my code in Julia, but my code runs faster without parallelization (serial for loops). Below, I follow the simple example from the Julia documentation and serial code is much faster than the parallel one. (Adding two matrices q and u)

```
@everywhere function myrange(q::SharedArray)
 idx = indexpids(q)
   if idx == 0
    # This worker is not assigned a piece
     return 1:0, 1:0
   end
  nchunks = length(procs(q))
  splits = [round(Int, s) for s in linspace(0,size(q,2),nchunks+1)]
  1:size(q,1), splits[idx]+1:splits[idx+1]
end

# Here's the kernel 
@everywhere function advection_chunk!(q, u, irange, jrange)
  @show (irange, jrange)  # display so we can see what's happening
   for j in jrange, i in irange
     q[i,j] = q[i,j] +  u[i,j]
   end
  q
end

advection_serial!(q, u) = advection_chunk!(q, u, 1:size(q,1), 1:size(q,2))

# Here's a convenience wrapper for a SharedArray implementation
@everywhere advection_shared_chunk!(q, u) = advection_chunk!(q, u, myrange(q)...)


function advection_shared!(q, u)
   @sync begin
     for p in procs(q)
        @async remotecall_wait(advection_shared_chunk!, p, q, u)
     end
   end
  q
end
```

Using these functions, I use @time to compare the computation time

```
q = SharedArray(Float64, (5,10000))
u = SharedArray(Float64, (5,10000))

advection_serial!(q, u)
advection_shared!(q, u)  # use @time after running both once
```

Then I got somewhat weird result...

1) serial code is about 40 times faster than parallel code (after adding 3 workers: 0.000576 seconds v.s. 0.023328 seconds)

2) parallel code gets slower as I add more workers.

Did I do something wrong? Is there anyway that I can make parallel code faster with this example?

Comment: There's a lot of overhead to parallel computation. Unless each worker is doing a fairly significant amount of work, you don't generally expect speedups.